# How to work with multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, python-requests

A multidimensional array is an array containing one or more arrays.This is a definition of multidimensional array in php and below is an example of multidimensional array

```
    [employee_experiences] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [company_name] => xyz
                [designation] => worker
                [job_description] => abc
                [started] => 2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z
                [ended] => 2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [company_name] => zyz
                [designation] => worker
                [job_description] => def
                [started] => 2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z
                [ended] => 2020-06-08T19:00:00.000Z
            )

    )
```

My question is that how can I get this format in python and save it to the the database I know python can't handle array instead python use lists

Comment: that looks more like  a dictionary

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of doing it in python:

```
employee_experiences = []

company_name = 'xyz'
designation = 'worker'
job_description = 'abc'
started = '2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z'
ended = '2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z'

employee_experiences.append([company_name, designation, job_description, started, ended])

company_name = 'zyz'
designation = 'worker'
job_description = 'def'
started = '2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z'
ended = '2020-06-08T19:00:00.000Z'

employee_experiences.append([company_name, designation, job_description, started, ended])
```

Another way is to create a function:

```
employee_experiences = []

def append_employee(company_name, designation, job_description, started, ended):
    employee_experiences.append([company_name, designation, job_description, started, ended])

append_employee('xyz', 'worker', 'abc', '2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z', '2020-06-09T19:00:00.000Z')
```

The best way would probably require learning how to use python classes.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an array of associate arrays.
Did you try using an ORM framework? They can map objects to relation schemes. Most web MVC frameworks support this feature. There are several for Python.
You need to define there the scheme, in a class code, using types they have, and then you can manipulate object to push and pull data in and from the database table. That is, you create a code which creates the scheme, not relying on a pre-existing database.